# How to maintain aspect ratio(while zooming) in the multiple subplots code in plotly?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-python

In the following code, how do I maintain the aspect ratio while zooming in? How do I implement a scale anchor in it, such that the y-axis should also zoom in while I zoom the x-axis through the range slider? I tried other answers given in the forum, but they are for single simple plots, not for multiple subplots with range sliders.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.offline as pyo

# Example data
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/farmaan/Downloads/goog1y.csv')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# Create the subplots
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, vertical_spacing=0.05)

# Add the OHLC chart to the upper subplot
fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(
    x=df['Date'],
    open=df['Open'],
    high=df['High'],
    low=df['Low'],
    close=df['Close'],
    increasing_line_color='green',
    decreasing_line_color='red',
    name='OHLC',
    yaxis='y1'
), row=1, col=1)

# Add the volume chart to the lower subplot
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=df['Date'],
    y=df['Volume'],
    name='Volume'
), row=2, col=1)

# Configure the subplots
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_rangeslider_visible=True,
    height=800,
    xaxis=dict(showticklabels=True,
               rangebreaks=[
                   dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"]), # hide weekends
               ]),
    yaxis=dict(domain=[0.5, 1], showticklabels=True),
    yaxis2=dict(domain=[0, 0.3], showticklabels=True, anchor='x', title='Volume'),
    
)


# Create an HTML file containing the plot
pyo.plot(fig, filename='ohlc_candles.html')
```